# compileSdkVersion is deprecated. If I change it to compileSdk, should I also change minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Since compileSdkVersion is deprecated I've changed it to:

```
android {
    compileSdk 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.package.test'
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        android.ndkVersion "22.1.7171670"
    }...
```

Should I also change minSdkVersion to minSdk and targetSdkVersion to targetSdk?
These two are not listed ad deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

CompileSdkVersion is surely deprecated.
From now use this:

```
android {
    compileSdk 34
    buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.my"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 10001
        versionName "1.00.01"
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CompileSdkVersion is not deprecated, in my opinion.
Two languages are available for writing Gradle files.

1. Groovy
2. Koltin

based on which terms you're seeing below will differ.

**build.gradle(groovy script)**

- compileSdkVersion
- minSdkVersion
- targetSdkVersion

**build.gradle.kts(kotlin dsl)**

- compileSdk
- minSdk
- targetSdk